# How to tell the "last" command to read from STDIN?

Tags: pipe, last

```
SERVER:~ # zcat /var/log/wtmp-20130827.gz | last -f -
last: -: No such file or directory
SERVER:~ #
```

Without uncompressing the wtmp file, how can I see the output of if it with the last command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last` doesn't support reading from a pipe. You can use `/dev/stdin` as a file name, but that's kind of useless since it only works if you're redirecting from a file in the first place.

Uncompress the file to a temporary file.

```
wtmp=$(mktemp)
zcat /var/log/wtmp-20130827.gz >|"$wtmp"
last -f "$wtmp"
rm -f "$wtmp"
```

Zsh has a form of process substitution `=(…)` which puts the output of a command in a temporary file.

```
last -f =(zcat /var/log/wtmp-20130827.gz)
```

Answer (score 0):

No way.

last(1) is not designed to be able to read stdin. Either /var/log/wtmp or -f xxx

It doesn't support '-'